# Unable to refer external module in TypeScript

Tags: module, typescript, external

I want to use an external module in my [TypeScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TypeScript) code, but it is failing. Specifically, I want to use methods from the referring [external.d.ts](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/express/express.d.ts) file in my TypeScript script.

My code is:

```
module test {

    //This is not working. I want to know the syntax to refer to express here.
    private express: typeof express = require("express");

    export testserver
    {
        constructor(private app:express.Application)
        {
          //Can not find express symbol
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does "failing " mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//This is not working. I want to know the syntax to refer to express here.
private express: typeof express = require("express");
```

Use `import`:

```
  import express = require("express");

  export testserver
  {
       constructor(private app:express.Application)
       {
       }
  }
```

And don't mix internal and external modules. More is in the YouTube video *[TypeScript Modules Demystified: Internal, AMD with RequireJS, CommonJS with Node.js](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1)*.

Answer (score 0):

This works even with

```
 import * as express from 'express';
```

But the problem is some times I am getting blank javascript file when I compile.Is this a known issue?I am new to the typescript correct me if anything wrong.Thank you.